# Difference between $GL(4,\mathbb{C})$ and $M(4,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, vector-spaces, notation, terminology

What is the difference between the notations $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ as mentioned [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101887/do-gamma-matrices-form-a-basis)? I couldn't find the latter notation when I googled it.

I know that the former is a group: General linear group of degree $n$ comprising of the set of $n\times n$ invertible matrices, together with the operation of ordinary matrix multiplication.

*What does the latter notation stand for? Does it represent the linear vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices with complex elements?*

Comment: Yes, what you say in italics is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries (including non-invertible matrices), as opposed to $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ which has only the invertible matrices.  The set $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ forms an $n^2$-dimensional complex vector space, and is also a ring using matrix multiplication.  (Combining these two structures, you can say that $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.)